# Sorting array gives all 0's

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So ive made a method which sorts the elements of an array. However, when i run the program and call the sort method, it displays an array of only 0's. This is the code:

```
    Vector vector = new Vector(length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++){
            if (vector.elements[i] < vector.elements[j]) {
                long temp = vector.elements[j];
                vector.elements[i] = vector.elements[j];
                vector.elements[j] = temp; 
            }
        }
    }

    return vector;
```

Please help!

Comment: Write this,long temp = vector.elements[i];  vector.elements[i] = vector.elements[j]; vector.elements[j] = temp;

Comment: You could add a simple System.out.println or debug it to see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparison technique is wrong. Please check the following, I updated your code. Hope it should work. Thanks!

```
for (int i = 0; i < length-1 ; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < length; j++){
        if (vector.elements[i] > vector.elements[j]){
            long temp = vector.elements[i];
            vector.elements[i] = vector.elements[j];
            vector.elements[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

It will sort the array in ascending order.

Comment: When i run the given code it still produces an output of all 0's.

Comment: Can you please let me know the definition of Vector?

Answer (score 1):

Your swapping is wrong. Instead of swapping the `i`'th and `j`'th elements you only assign the `j`'th element to the `i`'th position and leave the `j`'th element unchanged.

It should be :

```
            long temp = vector.elements[i]; // was j
            vector.elements[i] = vector.elements[j];
            vector.elements[j] = temp;
```

Comment: I swapped the `i` and `j` around but im still getting a vector of only 0's @Eran. Is there an issue with the loop itself wherein its not assigning the correct number to the variables?

Comment: @ShahrokhAryana Do you initialize your `vector.elements` array with non-zero values?

Comment: yes its initialised to non-zero, but the user can change the values at any time through the program but creating a new vector

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have not inserted any element in the vector. Still let me assume you have not mentioned that code here. Although it is irrelevant looping. As in each outer looping the largest element is moving here and there. If you want to sort by bubble sort then please follow the algorithm.
It should be like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < length; j++){
            if (vector.elements[i] < vector.elements[j]) {
                long temp = vector.elements[j];
                vector.elements[i] = vector.elements[j];
                vector.elements[j] = temp; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Secondly it will sort in descending order. I could not find the .elements[] method also in java 8.